# how can i simulate ma time series model and the residuals are poison distribution using R?

Tags: r, simulation

i want to make a simulation for moving average time series model but residuals are not normally distributed rather its poison , using R package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `arima.sim`. Specify the argument `rand.gen`, default is `rnorm`, but you can set it to `rpois`. You must provide a lambda.

```
# choose your ma
ma <- 0.7
# choose your lambda for the Poisson distribution
lambda <- 0.5
# choose length of your series
n <- 200


arima.sim(list(order = c(0,0,1), ma = ma), 
          rand.gen = function(x) rpois(x, lambda = lambda),
          n = n)
```